# All routes about a IP in my Router AS-PATH last AS number is Idle

Tags: router, ip, bgp

I can not ping the IP `202.137.151.185` from my router.

and in my router I show a IP's route, there gets the following information:

```
admin@EE-MX-RE1# run show route 202.137.151.185                                 

inet.0: 737549 destinations, 3625282 routes (737549 active, 0 holddown, 25 hidde
n)                                                                              
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both                                     

202.137.151.0/24   *[BGP/170] 3w0d 12:25:01, localpref 195                      
                      AS path: 64050 4837 9873 I, validation-state: unverified  
                    > to 103.198.146.173 via ae5.200                            
                    [BGP/170] 3w2d 05:43:18, localpref 190                      
                      AS path: 4134 4837 9873 I, validation-state: unverified   
                    > to 183.91.44.17 via ae1.0                                 
                    [BGP/170] 1d 02:12:32, localpref 120                        
                      AS path: 1299 45899 9873 I, validation-state: unverified  
                    > to 62.115.54.130 via ae7.0                                
                    [BGP/170] 3w2d 04:12:22, localpref 120, from 59.148.193.156 
                      AS path: 10103 4635 4651 9931 9873 I, validation-state: un
verified                                                                        
                    > to 61.244.64.225 via ae4.0                                
                    [BGP/170] 3w2d 04:25:04, localpref 110                      
                      AS path: 4809 4134 4837 9873 I, validation-state: unverifi
ed                                                                              
                    > to 210.48.136.73 via ae2.0                                
                    [BGP/170] 3w2d 04:12:30, localpref 80                       
                      AS path: 4809 4134 4837 9873 I, validation-state: unverifi
ed                                                                              
                    > to 210.48.136.237 via ae3.0
```

I find all the routes about it, the last AS number are Idle(`I`), whether this is because of the target IP address is in an Idle AS? I can do nothing in my router to let my router can access the IP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "Idle AS". The `I` at the end of the AS path does not stand for 'Idle'. It stands for "Learned from IGP", so the router you're checking it from learned this route from another router in your network.

You can read more about the output of `show route` commands in JunOS [here](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/command-summary/show-route.html).

As for the reason why you can't ping this IP address, there could be a number of reasons. ICMP can be blocked on that host (or by some device on the path), that IP may  have a problem reaching your network, etc.

Comment: ... or the host isn't on, or there's no return path, etc., etc.